# How to have alertDialog box disappear on button click?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I just want the alertDialog box to disappear when user hit the "Done" key on soft keyboard. I try to use the dismiss() method but it says cannot resolve 'allet11' which is my AlertDialog object.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button PicButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.picButton_ID);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_ID);
        Button topTextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.topButton_ID);
        Button bottonTextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bottomButton_ID);
        final TextView topText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.topText_ID);
        TextView bottomText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bottomText_ID);

        //Disables button if user has no camera
        if(!hasCamera()) {
            PicButton.setEnabled(false);
        }

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);



        topTextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {



                builder1.setMessage("Write your zinger here.");
                builder1.setCancelable(true);

                final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                builder1.setView(input);
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                input.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

                //checks if "Done" button on soft keyboard is clicked
                input.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                        if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                            //what happens when "Done" is clicked
                            topText.setText(input.getText().toString());
                            alert11.dismiss();


                        }
                        return false;

                    }

                });



                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                alert11.show();

            }

        });

    }

    //checks if user has a camera
    private boolean hasCamera(){
        return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY);
    }

    //Launcing the camera
    public void launchCamera(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        //take a picture and pass results along to onAcivityResult
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }

    //if you want to return the image taken
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                //get the photo
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap)extras.get("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to put this line `final AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();` before your `input.setOnEditorActionListener(...)` instead of your `AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();`.

Comment: You should call dialog, not a builder.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
final AlertDialog builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
```

Instead of

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```